# How do I show some static text for SSRS groups that are empty?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a query that groups by a particular column. Some of these groups have no entries and therefore are skipped. I would rather it state somehow

'GROUP XYZ IS EMPTY'

How do I do this ?

edit 1: You are correct and I did an outer join with the group as you suggested. It works but would be nice if I could have it say in the row 'There are no results' instead of it just being blank

Comment: A group with no entry simply doesn't exist, and so you can't display its name. If you get a list of names, let's say "Alice", "Bob" and "Charlie". How can you tell that "David" should also be contained in that list but is missing?

Comment: You need to create the data in your SQL - SSRS won't be able to figure out what is missing and then add it. Usually, you'll make a (*temp*) table of **ALL possible groups** and then LEFT JOIN your current results to it so your missing groups are included but have a NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an expression in your tablix detail textbox. For example:

```
=IIF(Fields!YourField.Value = Nothing, "This one is empty", Fields!YourField.Value)
```

Comment: How will this resolve the issue? there will be nothing to display. The only way is to left join the actual data to a distinct list of groups.